# Are SOAP, WSDL and WS-* part of SOA?

Tags: web-services, soa

Truth be told I have no clue whether SOA describes/recommends which protocols web services should use for interoperability, or whether it also defines some of the protocols, or does it just recommend the design patterns and best practices services should follow in order to achieve interoperability

Anyways, are SOAP, WSDL and WS-* specifications part of SOA and thus outside of SOA arhitecture we use other means to achieve interoperability between web services, or can/are they used independently of SOA?

thank you

Comment: SOA is... just the Same Old Architecture (but with new buzzwords)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say they are part of an approach to SOA.  SOA is a set of principles, just as Object Oriented design really is at its core a set of principles.

You do not need SOAP or WSDL to have an SOA.

Comment: "You do not need SOAP or WSDL to have an SOA." But are SOAP, WC-* and WSDL also used by web services outside of SOA?

Comment: In theory yes.  You can use SOAP for something and that something need not be part of an OVERALL SOA.  But in practice thats probably what it is used most for.

Comment: Just one more question - are WC-* specs defined by SOA?

Comment: @user437291 check this out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_oriented_architecture

Comment: The link doesn't tell whether WS-* is part of SOA definition or whether it's a separate entity

Comment: @user437921, did you read the part about soa and webservice protocols?

Comment: ups, no. I used browser's search feature to look for "WS-" string. Anyways, based on the description ( posted below for a future reference ) it appears WS-* spec are defined independently of SOA and thus can be used outside SOA systems. Anyways, thank you for your help

Comment: "Implementors commonly build SOAs using web services standards (for example, SOAP) that have gained[when?] broad industry acceptance. These standards (also referred to as Web Service specifications) also provide greater interoperability and some protection from lock-in to proprietary vendor software. One can, however, implement SOA using any service-based technology, such as Jini, CORBA or REST."

Comment: glad you found what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check this question for a lot of useful answers and resources for what SOA is about:

[Is it OK to Call a Service from Another Service in an SOA Architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660156/is-it-ok-to-call-a-service-from-another-service-in-an-soa-architecture)

I hope it helps!