# standard other than SOAP+WSDL to implement a SOA

Tags: architecture, soap, wsdl, soa

I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179208/are-soap-wsdl-and-ws-part-of-soa)

However I am still not clear what are the other way to implement a SOA architecture with out using technologies like SOAP/WSDL.
I am working on applications deployed to websphere and weblogic app server. It would be more helpful if you can give example related to such kind of environments.

Answer (score 2):

You can use RESTful services instead of SOAP/WSDL...

Answer (score 1):

First be clear about **SOA**. Many people thinks, you are using **SOA** then you must have web services. I think that is wrong. **SOA** consist of many individual, atomic modules known as service. Now, you have to expose **endpoints for accessesing those service** in(means inside your application) and out(out side your application).

There are many ways by which you can expose end point of your SOA service:

1. Using web service.
2. Using RMI (stub/skeleton)
3. Using some messaging middleware (JMS/ActiveMQ etc.)
4. Using JSON.
5. Using your custome XML schema.
6. TCP socket directly to service.
7. Or any other way you know.

We have build a **SOA using (in JAVA)JBoss jBPM, JBoss Drools and JMS/ActiveMQ**. We have different end points of our services as per our requirement of specific service. Like, some service need to publish data regularly, so we have created those service as web services, **custom XML schema requests/response**(some where JSON). Some services are not exposed out side of application, those have endpoints of RMI, or JMS queue/topic etc. Some service can be called using simple method call(VM endpoints).

Take **PersistenceService for example**. It is responsible for managing database access and other operations. So, any service in SOA want database access, need to use PersistenceService. Since, this service is not important for end user (or we can say out side of application), you can expose end points of that service using direct method call(VM end points), RMI stub/skeleton, create a JMS queue/topic on which it is listening on etc.

Now, we have **UserManagementService** that is responsible for user managemet tasks like authenticate, authorize, manage role etc. It will be used by your application for login/logout like stuff from user. So, you can expose it as a web service or you custome XML schema request/response.

So, we can say that SOA services are used inside your application and out side of application. Depends on that its endpoints differes. End points of services will depend on the way you want to use that service.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
Yes, I totally agree with you. But that is true for services that are available as a business functions as you said. But you can apply the same SOA service concepts inside environment of your application. You can design your application in SOA way such that all services in your appliacation can behave like individual SOA service whether they are public service or core service of your application(like PersistenceService, ReportingService, LoggingService et.) This way you can also cluster you application at service level(business service as well as core services) where services are distributed at different nodes. By the way(I know), this is not your questions's answer. You can use your custom XML request/response as a  replcement of web services.

Comment: :Thanks for response but don't agree with your complete part..SOA is architecture-ing your IT systems in such a way that system exposes useful business functions as services in platform neutral way..SOAP became popular because it is an XML application and XML is platform independent representation of structured information...so when u mention "expose service using RMI"...I don't believe that is correct statement..RMI is tightly bound to Java environment..